# Why do I have to explicitly nilify blanks for the shoulda matcher `inclusion:` validation to pass?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, shoulda

I have a string column in my database that holds a time zone. Valid values include `nil` or anything that ActiveSupport recognizes as a timezone

I use shoulda-matchers to write specs for my model validation:

```
# app/models/my_model.rb
class MyModel < ApplicationRecord
  validates :timezone, inclusion: ActiveSupport::TimeZone::MAPPING.keys, allow_nil: true
end

# spec/models/my_model_spec.rb
describe "timezone" do
  it do 
    should validate_inclusion_of(:timezone).
      in_array(ActiveSupport::TimeZone::MAPPING.keys).
      allow_blank
    end
end
```

It threw an error:

```
Failure/Error: it { should validate_inclusion_of(:timezone).in_array(ActiveSupport::TimeZone::MAPPING.keys).allow_blank }

     MyModel did not properly validate that
     :timezone is either ‹"International Date Line West"›, ‹"Midway Island"›,
     ‹"American Samoa"›, ‹"Hawaii"›, ‹"Alaska"›, ‹"Pacific Time (US &
     .....
     .....
     .....
     ‹"Auckland"›, ‹"Wellington"›, ‹"Nuku'alofa"›, ‹"Tokelau Is."›, ‹"Chatham
     Is."›, or ‹"Samoa"›, but only if it is not blank.
       After setting :timezone to ‹""›, the matcher expected the
       MyModel to be valid, but it was invalid
       instead, producing these validation errors:

       * timezone: ["is not included in the list"]
```

Shoulda matchers sets the column to `""` and expects that the validations should pass. But why is that expected? `nil` is strictly allowed but a blank string value shouldn't be, right?

Is there a more proper way to set this up that I've missed?

To work around it, I use us a `before_validation` block. (And I know of the nilify_blanks gem that does the same thing). But it feels odd that I'd have to include that at all

```
before_validation do
  self[:timezone] = nil if self[:timezone].blank?
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.blank?` is an ActiveSupport method that returns true for `nil`, `false` and more imporantly `""` (an empty string).

Thats why `allow_blank` tests with an empty string. Use [`allow_nil`](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers/blob/afa6a7b6661a0d4450d330922c2c930ea2f3ff68/lib/shoulda/matchers/active_model/validate_inclusion_of_matcher.rb#L203) instead.

```
# spec/models/my_model_spec.rb
describe "timezone" do
  it do 
    should validate_inclusion_of(:timezone).
      in_array(ActiveSupport::TimeZone::MAPPING.keys).
      allow_nil
  end
end
```